# Cisco compatible VPN option not visible

Tags: plugins, vpnc

I have installed `vpnc` and `network-manager-vpnc`, but when using `network-manager` to add a vpn connection, the Cisco compatible is not available, only ptpp.

Answer (score 0):

Check here. http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tag/cisco-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-12-04

If that does not work you may need to be part of an group that allows you to create and connect to VPNS. If you are already an administrator of the computer, try adding yourself to other groups that have to do with networking related permissions.

dialout,netdev or proxy. Although I don't see a specific VPN group, if you have a VPN group then I would assume that one to be it.

Comment: Typically, installing the component is all they'll need.  That and `network-manager-vpnc-gnome` which is the GUI frontend components ;)